# Use CSS only if you are certain page

Tags: html, css

I need to load a couple styles on one specific page. 
The problem lies in the CMS I'm using
I can't change the class to the div and make it specific so I can add styles to it and I also can't add specific styles to the page itself. It all has to be done in the main style sheet. 
I know you can use conditional CSS depending on the browser but... 
**Can you load styles based on what page you are on?** 
So if blank.html then load these 2 styles?

Comment: If you don't have php access to add an if clause or permission to add a jquery you could try an htaccess trick.

Comment: Is there no class attribute that specifies the page e.g. in body tag `page-id-8` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use the CSS `@document` at-rule, but only in Firefox under the `@-moz-document` prefix. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document.

Comment: This is experimental technology and only supported by Firefox. I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Nice, I'd never heard of that until now! Have ten of the finest imaginary internet points! (Obviously with awareness of the cross-browser problems…)